# Check if integers exist between a value in three elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array with a buffer of 5 values coming in at the same time;

```
int max = 5; //max value for the array

std::array<int, 5> myarray;
for(int ii = 0; ii< max; ii++) myarray[i%5] = faces[i].x; //don't care about faces[i]

for(int i = 0; i < myarray.size(); i++) std::cout<< myarray[i] << ",";
```

Now, I want to check if at least 3 of the elements in the array consist of a given value (int) between +50 and -50, the numbers in the array will never be negative. Any ides of how this could be done?

Comment: This can be done by a crow. Evidence suggest that [crows can count up to (and including) 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_intelligence#Counting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it via for loop easily.

```
int cnt = 0;
int flg = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myarray.size(); i++){
     if(myarray[i] >= -50 && myarray[i] <= 50){
         cnt++;
      } else if(myarray[i] < 0){
         flg = 1;
      }
}

if(cnt < 3 || flg == 1){
    //Error statement
}
```

Comment: @HumbleMan : Did you get the solution?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : May be by looking at the code, he learns how to do it.

Comment: Yes sir! But I guess that a[i] in my case should be myarray[i], right?

Comment: Yes. I am sorry . I missed it

Comment: @PriyanshGoel Btw, does this myarray[i] >= -50 && myarray[i] <= 50 really check if the values are in range of 50? It is not doing what I want =/

Comment: It checks that the values are between -50 and 50 (inclusive)

Comment: @PriyanshGoel Ah yes indeed, I think you misunderstood me, it should not check if the values are between -50 and 50 but if they differ of more than 50 more or 50 less. Would really appreciate if you could edit the answer according to this, if you know how to do.

Comment: I don't get your question. Differ of more than 50 more or 50 less? Can you explain it by example?